# Formal Proof for $\textbf{Vect}_k\cong\textbf{Mat}_k$?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, category-theory, vectors, monoidal-categories

Where this question came from: I was researching about the graphical languages for monoidal categories involving the category $\textbf{PROP}$ and wanted to see if I could create a graphical language for $\textbf{Vect}_k$ because of $\textbf{Mat}_k$. (probably not the exact reason however this is what I remember)

Let $\textbf{Vect}_k$ be the category of vector spaces for some field $k$ and $\textbf{Mat}_k$ be the category of matrices under the same field $k$.

I know that we can define an equivalence between categories between $\textbf{Vect}_k$ and $\textbf{Mat}_k$ because given vector spaces $V=k^n$ consisting of all $n$-tuples over $k$, and $U=k^m$ consisting of all $m$-tuples over $k$ where $U,V\in\text{Obj}(\textbf{Vect}_k)$, then $\text{Hom}_k(V,U)$ creates the vector space $k^{m\times n}$ representing the set of all $m\times n$ matrices over $k$. Thus showing that $k^{m\times n}\in\text{Obj}(\textbf{Mat}_k)$. If $X=k^{m\times n}$ and $Y=k^{n\times q}$ (set of all $n\times q$ matrices over $k$), then $\text{Hom}(X,Y)=X\otimes Y$ where the tensor product, $\otimes$, is the cross product between the set of matrices $X$ and $Y$. The cross product rules still apply where $\text{Hom}(Y,X)=\emptyset$.

Now lets define the functor $F:\textbf{Vect}_k\to\textbf{Mat}_k$. We have a morphism $f:V\to U$ and the image of $f$ in $\textbf{Mat}_k$, $Ff$, will connect the image of $V$ to the image of $U$. Now I am pretty sure I might be thinking about this wrongly and I hope you could help me with this but I think that $Ff:FV\to FU$ is a morphism from the set of all $m\times1$ matrices to the set if all $1\times n$ matrices. Thus makes $\text{Hom}_{Ff}(FV\to FU)=FV\otimes FU$ which means the cross product between matrices $FV=k^{m\times1}$ and $FU=k^{1\times n}$.

I know this connection however I do not know how to form a formal equivalence proof for $\textbf{Vect}_k\cong\textbf{Mat}_k$. If I could get some help I would greatly appreciate it.

**Sources:**

- https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2008/06/24/the-category-of-matrices-iv/
- http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Software/magma/text387.html
- http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Software/magma/text388.html
- http://users.ecs.soton.ac.uk/ps/papers/ih.pdf
- https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/qpl2015/slides/sobocinski-tutorial.pdf

Comment: It would help to know what the objects and morphisms are in $\mathbf{Mat}_k$. I don't think you've stated it correctly.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein I just finished. Let me know if you need more clarification. I will be more than happy to clarify.

Comment: It looks like you're associating $Hom_k(V, U)$, a space of morphisms in $\mathbf{Vect}_k$, to $k^{m \times n}$, an object in $\mathbf{Mat}_k$. So you haven't defined a functor.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Lets define the functor $F:\textbf{Vect}_k\to\textbf{Mat}_k$. We have a morphism $f:V\to U$ and the image of f in $\textbf{Mat}_k$, $Ff$, will connect the image of $V$ to the image of $U$. Now I am pretty sure I might be thinking about this wrongly and I hope you could help me with this but I think that $Ff:FV\to FU$ is a morphism from the set of all $m\times 1$ matrices to the set if all $1\times n$ matrices. Thus makes $\text{Hom}_{Ff}(FV\to FU)=FV\otimes FU$ which means the cross product between matrices $FV$ and $FU$. (tell me if I should add this to the question body)

Comment: So you're defining $F(V)$ to be the object $k^{m \times 1}$?

Comment: Yes, I think that should be added to your question.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Yes.

Comment: Perhaps you're trying to prove the category of $k$-modules and that of $M_n(k)$-modules are equivalent?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff What do you mean by "$M_n(k)$-modules?" Also, I do not know if that is what I am trying to prove; however if you expand on this I might be able to see a connection.

Comment: What is the category of matrices over a vector space? What are the morphisms between two matrices? Why are you suggesting such equivalence exists? Perhaps you read somewhere, phrased differently, what I said above: there is an equivalence of categories between $k$-vector spaces and $M_n(k)$-modules --- this is an instance of a Morita equivalence between categories of modules. I'm sorry if some terms seem to be over your head.

Comment: In particular, you can state that "the ring $k$ and the ring $M_n(k)$ of matrices over $k$ are Morita equivalent", which perhaps got mixed up into what you're trying to prove, i.e. that "vector spaces and matrices are equivalent categories."

Comment: @StefanPerko I do not but I assume that I was.

Comment: Okay, my comment was incorrect anyway. I was referring to finite-dimensional spaces...

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I doubt this is a question about Morita equivalence. My gut reaction was similar to Stefan's, expressing the equivalence of finite dimensional vector spaces to the skeleton category of $k^n$ for each $n$, but it seems Julian is going for something different here...

Comment: I think you should explicitely describe, where you got this idea from (ideally name a source).

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I understand that what you are saying is a little over me even though I am aware of Morita equivalences. However I would like to see you do a full explanation because I do want to learn about all possibilities

Comment: @StefanPerko I will edit my question to have the sources

Comment: I realize where this question came from. I was researching about the graphical languages for monoidal categories involving the category $\textbf{PROP}$ and wanted to see if I could create a graphical language for $\textbf{Vect}_k$ because of $\textbf{Mat}_k$.

Comment: The first source you listed already is talking about the statement I was referring to. There is even a proof given there.

Comment: @StefanPerko Oh I was just thinking he was throwing ideas down for the possible equivalence proof. I just thought it was not formal.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff If you do not mind, would you be able to explain the Morita equivalence approach you were talking about earlier? I just want to be exposed to it and learn from your explanation.

Comment: @JulianRachman Some time later.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Ok thank you. You can just write it as an answer if the explanation will need space. I hope to see you answer in the near future.

Comment: What's with the reopen votes? The question hasn't changed since the closure.